# How can I make only one section of my ASP.NET page load when the user clicks a TreeView node?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a page with a sidebar on the left that has a TreeView with items that currently reloads the whole page when you click one of the items. I only want to reload the right side, which is a content view text and pictures depending on which node you're on... everything else is in the Master Page. The people that will use this website have really limited bandwidth so it would make more sense not to reload the whole page, I think...

How can I make only the content part reload when a link is clicked? I was looking at UpdatePanel, but I'm not sure if that would go in the Master Page or in the content page... very new to ASP.NET.

Comment: Is the sidebar markup in the master page, or in the content page?

Comment: It's in the master page.

Comment: How do I expose the tree view as public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Master Page

```
<asp:TreeView ID="myTreeView" />
```

Master Page Code Behind. This exposes myTreeView as a public property.

```
public TreeView MyTreeView
{
    get {return myTreeView;} //note the capitalization
    set;
}
```

Content Page

```
<%-- Put this below the Page directive) It makes the Master Page strongly typed. Use the path to your Master page --%>
<%@ MasterType  virtualPath="~/MasterPage.master"%>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="MyTreeView" EventName="SelectedNodeChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <%-- Rest of your page content goes here --%>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

What this does it make your TreeView available as a public property. By default, controls have a private or protected scope (can't remember which). Then it makes your Master Page strongly typed, so that you can access Master Page public properties, functions, and fields from the content page. Then it registers the TreeView as an async post back trigger so it will cause your UpdatePanel to update.

Note that I haven't test this. I steer clear of UpdatePanels as much as possible in favor of jQuery AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Use the update panel inside content place holders and have async triggers to the update panel. This will allow you to have more control on the partial rendering and avoid issues which may arise when nesting updatepanels and having javascript frameworks like jquery event bindings to work properly